# How can i draw outline or shadow to a text with using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, fonts

In my C++ project, im using OpenCV library to implement image processing algorithms.
I want to draw outline or shadow to texts that i drew on frames with using OpenCV's putText function. I have researched about it but only solution that i found is drawing the same text twice. This solution drops the FPS of my overall project because im drawing many texts on the frames.

Do i have to code a new font library for my project or is there any simpler solutions to it?

thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried FreeType with different ttf fonts that i found in various websites. Yes, there are some fonts that has default shadow or outlines in it. The problem here is i can't change the colour of the shadow of it. Yes, i can change the colour of overall font but shadow colour becomes the same as the font. I want black or white shadow that can highlight the text.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do is draw the text once to an empty image, say A. then mask your main image several times with A, shifting A as required.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Cris. Would you explain the solution a little more? Isn't the masking two images costly like putText function? What are the advantages?

Comment: @Velandrie masking is a lot cheaper than rendering text. Rendering text is expensive. You could easily speed up all text rendering by rendering each letter once, store those single-letter bitmaps in a hard-coded table in your code, and then just mask each letter you need into your image. OpenCV's vector fonts are nice because you can scale them as you please, but they're not efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestion and informations Cris. I'll implement your suggested technique to my project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use freetype. OpenCV can be compiled with FreeType which will allow you to load fonts from ttf files. then you can look up for a free font online which suits four needs of make your own ttf file.

Here is a link on how to use FreeType with opencv.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dfa/classcv_1_1freetype_1_1FreeType2.html

Comment: Thank you for comment, guivi. I tried FreeType with different ttf fonts that i found in various websites. Yes, there are some fonts that has default shadow or outlines in it. The problem here is i can't change the colour of the shadow of it. Yes, i can change the colour of overall font but shadow colour becomes the same as the font. I want black shadow that can highlight the text.